# Select first value in select menu with jquery

Tags: jquery, select

I have this Jquery code below, but when I run this it doesn't select the first value by default. How can I select the first value in this select menu with Jquery?

HTML:

```
   <select class="form-control" id="txtAmountDays">
```

Jquery:

```
   day = $(this).data('id');

   var options="";
   var end_period = 24;
   for(var i=day;i<=end_period;i++)
   {
     options+="<option value='"+i+"'>"+i+"</option>";
   }       
   $("#txtAmountDays").html(options);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `selectedIndex` property of the select element to `0` using `.prop()` method:

```
$("#txtAmountDays").html(options).prop('selectedIndex', 0);
```

Or use `.val()` method:

```
$("#txtAmountDays").html(options).val(day);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't do it! I'm running this on an on "click" event and in Chrome. Can't see where it fails.

Comment: `selectedIndex` is a JavaScript property **not** a HTML one :)

Comment: @mattytommo We are using `html` as setter, it doesn't return HTML, `prop` sets the `seletedIndex` property of the select element.

Comment: @undefined Well, I created a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Qw89C/ and in the fiddle it works perfect! But not in my code.. huhu

Comment: But in the fiddle I don't even need to add `.val(day);` maybe it could be something in the Twitter bootstrap framework?

Comment: @Kim And now check your original code, it works itself, http://jsfiddle.net/Qw89C/1/ , this is the default behaviour of the select element, by default the first option is selected, the problem is something else.

Comment: The value was overwritten later in the code,`<embarrassing>`, thanks guys for your time :)